# Verify Files in a folder

Tags: php, sha1

I want to verify files stored in a directory, so i wrote this script.

```
<?php
$files = scandir('..');
for ($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++)
{
 $file2 = realpath($files[$i]);
 if (!is_dir($file2))
  $hash = sha1_file($file2);
 else
  $hash = 'Dir';
 echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.$file2.'</td><td>'.$hash.'</td><td>'.date ("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime($file2)).'</td></tr>';
 $i;
}
?>
```

it works nice, but if i include this script from a deeper a directory then it fails.

```
-www
 |_Sou
   |_Inner
     |_MoreInner
```

my script is located in inner folder and want to access it from MoreInner folder using `include` but it shows error `FILE NOT FOUND/ PERMISSION DENIED`

- What i want to do
  To get SHA1_FILE of files stored in the just above directory.

Comment: The error says you might have a file permission problem.  You might need to change the permissions to read access using [chmod](http://php.net/chmod).

Comment: I'd suggest making this a function with the base path as a parameter. This way you'll have a lot more control regardless from where you call that function.

Comment: @Keoki i'm testing this on my home PC and PHP have access to all the files, @Yoshi can you share some code ?

Comment: Do not post code that is commented out without explaining why it is relevant.

Comment: @OSwald i showed the commented code coz i thought perhaps the alternative code can better than the working one !

Comment: simply use vardumps and check if they give u file data or empty arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`RecurisveDirectoryIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) would be the most elegant way:

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('..', FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_FILEINFO | FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item) {
    if (!$item->isDir()) {
        $hash = sha1_file($item->getRealPath());
    } else {
        $hash = 'Dir';
    }
    echo $item->getRealPath().' '.$hash.' '.date ("F d Y H:i:s.", $item->getMTime())."\n";
}
```

Comment: Which line? Try to print the current `$item` with `var_dump()`.

Comment: Most often using `..` in includes is not a very wise option. Try using absolute paths to the directory you want to parse - you can make use of the constants `__DIR__` (if on PHP >= 5.3) or `__FILE__` which point to the absolute path of the file the code is in (or the directory of this file).

Answer (score 0):

As for the code example how to convert your code into a function and add a parameter for the path:

Make this function globally available to any scripts of your application where-ever in which directory you place them for your application:

```
function verfiyFiles($path) {
 $files = scandir($path);
 for ($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++)
 {
  $file2 = realpath($files[$i]);
  if (!is_dir($file2))
   $hash = sha1_file($file2);
  else
   $hash = 'Dir';
  echo '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.$file2.'</td><td>'.$hash.'</td><td>'.date ("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime($file2)).'</td></tr>';
  $i;
 }
}
```

Then within any script of your application you can make use of it:

```
verfiyFiles($path); # where $path is a path to the directory, e.g. '..'
```